How to create and link a cmake interface library
How to create a cmake interface library(header only library) and link it in another project
Interface library printer contains three files CMakeLists.txt, print.hpp and print.inl
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(printer VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_library(printer INTERFACE print.hpp print.inl)

set_target_properties(printer PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 20)
set_target_properties(printer PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)

print.hpp
#ifndef PRINT_H
#define PRINT_H

template<typename T>
void print(const T& t);

#include "print.inl"

#endif

print.inl
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void print(const T& t) {
   std::cout << t << std::endl;
}

Print_App project includes the above interface library
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(print_app VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(print_app
   main.cpp
)

set_target_properties(print_app PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 20)
target_link_libraries(print_app INTERFACE printer)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)

main.cpp
#include <iostream>

// how to include the below header file without specifying the relative path like below
// #include "print.hpp"
#include "../printer/print.hpp"

int main() {
   std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;

   print(10);
   print("abc");
   print(1.23456789);
}

In the Makefile of print_app, I see no mention of printer library.

What is the relationship between these two projects when printer_app is to be built?

It just calls the print function that's present in the printer library. I know it's useless. Just trying to understand the purpose of interface library

They are not, for instance, parts of the same CMake build tree? They're completely
independent projects?

you mean I should include printer library as a sub directory add_subdirectory?

I don't know. It's unclear in what way these projects are (to be) related and
only you can clarify it. Are they to be sub-projects of the same project?
Is one to be a sub-project of the other? Are they even under a single directory at
present that you wish to make the root of a CMake build? Or is the printer project
perhaps to be an upstream dependency of the printer_app project that should be
installed somewhere first?

target_link_libraries(print_app INTERFACE printer) - With INTERFACE keyword you are NOT linking the print_app with the printer. That keyword means that only consumers of print_app will be linked. (And an executable target cannot have consumers.)

@MikeKinghan you can think of it as the printer library is a sub-project of print_app project

@Tsyvarev could you please explain in detail

Meaning of PUBLIC/PRIVATE/INTERFACE keywords in target_link_libraries is described in documentation. As you could find from that documentation, INTERFACE doesn't link the library itself.
